# Can't serve static files in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Im using jade with express.
This is my express code for serving static files:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/frontend"));
```

And this is my jade code in layout.jade:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')

script(src='/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js')
script(src='/app.js')
```

For some reason stackoverflow doesn't allow me to show my folder structure but I have every file mentioned here in my frontend folder located in the root directory.
I tried commenting out express.static and using the full path but that also doesn't work.

I'm getting the 404 error.

Comment: Did you try `link(rel='stylesheet', href='/frontend/css/style.css')`

Comment: What is `__dirname` in your setup?  Can you `console.log()` it?  Is it the root directory?

Comment: I tried putting /frontend/ and it doesn't work.
How do I console.log __dirname on the server?

Comment: You add the line of code `console.log(__dirname);` right before the line that contains `express.static()`.  Then, when you run your server, you look on the console to see what it outputs when the server starts up.

Comment: It seems this is the issue, it doesn't take me to root but to /backend/.
How do I set it to root?

Comment: Should commenting out express.static and using the full path in the jade work? Because for me it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

The above code you posted will expose the assets on `/`.  To expose them on `/frontend`, you need to use the following.

`app.use(express.static("frontend", __dirname + "/frontend"));`

If you want to create a “virtual” (since the path does not actually exists in the file system) path prefix for the files served by express.static, you can specify a mount path for the static directory, as shown below:

`app.use('/static', express.static('public'));`

Answer (score -1):

```
app.use('/frontend', express.static('frontend'));
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/frontend/css/style.css')
```

Comment: This is something different than how the OP wants it to work.  It is not required that the OP use /frontend in front of every file on the client side which is what you are recommending.

Comment: This doesn't work aswell.
This is my console error:
GET http://localhost:3000/frontend/css/style.css 404 (Not found)